# Taylor Series Expansion $ f(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)^\frac{1}{x} $

Tags: calculus

I am trying to expand the following equation using Taylor's method:

$$ f(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)^\frac{1}{x} $$

$$ f'(x) =\left(-\frac{\ln\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)\right)}{x^2}+\frac{\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)\,\sec\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)}{x}\right) \left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)\right)^\frac{1}{x}$$

However, $f'[0]$ and $f''[0]$ are undefined. Is there a way to expand the above equation using Taylor's method.

Comment: Your function has a removable singularity at $x=0$. So you must find the  $\lim_{x\to 0} f^{(n)}(x),\,\,n=0,1,2...$ Moreover $\tan\left(x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)  =\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi }{4}-x\right)}$, so your function is even. You can ignore odd degrees.

Answer (score 1):

$$f=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)^\frac{1}{x}\implies \log(f)=\frac{1}{x}\log\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)\right)$$
$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)=1+2 x+2 x^2+\frac{8 x^3}{3}+\frac{10 x^4}{3}+\frac{64 x^5}{15}+\frac{244
   x^6}{45}+\frac{2176 x^7}{315}+O\left(x^8\right)$$
$$\log\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)\right)=2 x+\frac{4 x^3}{3}+\frac{4 x^5}{3}+\frac{488 x^7}{315}+O\left(x^8\right)$$
$$\log(f)=2+\frac{4 x^2}{3}+\frac{4 x^4}{3}+\frac{488 x^6}{315}+O\left(x^8\right)$$
$$f=e^{\log(f)}=e^2\left(1+\frac{4 x^2}{3}+\frac{20 x^4}{9}+\frac{10552 x^6}{2835}+O\left(x^8\right) \right)$$

Comment: Is the last step-> $e^2 \times e^{(\text{remaining powers of x})}$ and then the expansion of $e^x$ neglecting the others as 1?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi. Yes ! I wrote $f=e^{\log(f)}$. It is the basic composition of Taylor series. Don't tell that to my wife : I felt in love with Taylor (series) and Padé (approximants) 63+ years ago.