# nonlinear stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I have problem with solving this nonlinear SDE
$$dX_t=X_t(1+X^{2}_t)dt + (1+X^{2}_t)dW_t$$
So far I've tried using Ito's formula but without any success.
Could you give me an advice on how to start with this equation?

Comment: Not sure whether this SDE has closed form solution.

Comment: You mean it doesn't fulfill the existence theorem?

Comment: This equation satisfies the Lipschitz condition, so, it has a unique condition. However, it is not sure that it is possible to obtain this solution analytically.

Comment: Oh really? When I was checking Lipschitz condition I couldn't bound it. I tried $$|x+x^3-y-y^3|+|1+x^2-1-y^2| \leq |x-y|(1+|x^2 +xy + y^2|+|x+y|)$$ but $$(1+|x^2 +xy + y^2|+|x+y|)$$ doesn't have maximum.

Comment: You should rather apply the [local Lipschitz condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4808505/195378): for any closed region $B_N$ that $x,y \in B_N$, the equation satisfies the Lipschitz condition (the term you mentionned is bounded in $B_N$).

Comment: Thank you for replying. Do you have any idea on how I could calculate moments $EX_t, EX^2_{t}, EX^3_{t}$ and $Var(X_t)$?

Comment: Finally, the closed form solution of this SDE is founded.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the Ito's lemma to the function $\arctan(X_t)$:
$$\begin{align}
d\arctan(X_t) &= \frac{1}{1+X_t^2}dX_t + \frac{1}{2}\cdot  \left(-\frac{2X_t}{(1+X_t^2)^2} \right) \cdot d\langle X,X \rangle _t  \\
&=\frac{1}{1+X_t^2}\left( X_t(1+X^{2}_t)dt + (1+X^{2}_t)dW_t \right) + \frac{1}{2}\cdot  \left(-\frac{2X_t}{(1+X_t^2)^2} \right) \cdot (1+X^{2}_t)^2 dt \\
d\arctan(X_t)&=dW_t
\end{align}$$
Then
$$\arctan(X_t) -\arctan(X_0) = W_t$$
that is
$$\color{red}{X_t =\tan\left( W_t + C\right)}  \hspace{1cm} \text{for } C\in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm sorry to interrupt you again but could you tell me how to calculate $EX_t$ when we have a closed form solution? I'm trying to do that by sticking to the definition of $EX$ of continous random variable but without any success. Btw my $X_t =\tan\left( W_t + \frac{\pi}{4} \right)$ since $X_0=1$ in my excercise.

Comment: @bobbyshmurda In the exercise, $\mathbb{E}(X_t),\mathbb{E}(X_t^3)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_t^3)$ are litterately required to be calculated? Mathematica isn't able to give a closed form expressions for these expectations. An approximate solution is to use the [Taylor series expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3815146/195378) for the function $\tan(W_t + \pi/4)$ and after that using the fact that $\mathbb{E}(W_t^n)$ can be analytically calculated (however, I think this solution may be not the  expected solution).

Comment: There's a hint in my exercise that if you have a nonlinear stochastic equation that can be converted to linear one, you should find moments for $f(X_t)$ where $f$ is some function.

Comment: @bobbyshmurda Perhaps when you have the solution of calculating $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$, could you share it with us?

Comment: @bobbyshmurda Have you had yet the solution for the calculating of $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$? (I believe that it cannot be calculated with closed-form expression).